# MacOS Catalina how to change windows size without buttons?

Tags: macos, finder, adobe

I have a big problem with Adobe After Effects launched on macOS Catalina:

Yesterday I worked with a second Display in 2K resolution and, like in Adobe programs, you cannot open them in a fully new Desktop so I just pressed the `+` button to fill the rest of my desktop size.

Today I want to work with Full HD Display and I cannot change my size of Adobe After Effects! It's beyond my desktop!

How to bring it to original sizes or move program which allows me to drag and resize it manually?

[image]

Comment: I don't have AE, but from a quick look at Ps, if you check the View menu, is there a Screen Mode sub-menu? If so, try toggling between modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the version involved, but you should be able to hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key and double click the bottom edge of the window to resize it.

Comment: Many thanks! You saved a lot of my time! But double click doesn't fix this, holding the option key and resize bottom edge changed me a top edge too